# prove this nice inequality $\left|\prod_{i=1}^{n}(a_{i}-a_{i+1})\right|\le \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{16}$

Tags: inequality

Let $n$ be odd number, and $a_{i}\ge 0$, such that
$$2(a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n})=n$$
Show that
$$\left|\prod_{i=1}^{n}(a_{i}-a_{i+1})\right|\le \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{16}$$

where $a_{n+1}=a_{1}$

Seeing this inequality reminds me to use this conclusion to deal with it.
$$S_{AOB}=\frac{1}{2}|a_{1}b_{2}-a_{2}b_{1}|$$
where $A(a_{1},b_{1}),B(a_{2},b_{2}),O(0,0)$

It seems that this problem will involve a problem of maximum geometric area, perhaps it can be handled this way

Comment: I find it interesting that $n$ being odd is necessary here (which it definitely is).

Comment: My draft of partial proof. Step 1: If there is increasing (or decreasing) sequence of length $4$ ($a, b, c, d$), then their product is larger by replacing then into $a, b+c, 0, d$ ($a, 0, b+c, d$ if sequence is decreasing). Step 2: If there is $2$ or more monotonic sequence of length $3$, then the product can be larger by rearranging to remove both monotonic sequence. Step 3: The product is bigger if all the $a_i$s which are smaller than their neighbors are $0$.

Comment: Can you provide some context? Where does the inequality come from? Why should it hold? Are there examples where equality holds? Are there counterexamples for even $n$?

Comment: I have a strong feeling that using the complex numbers or in general the roots of unity in complex plane might help a lot but can't see a way through it

Comment: Waiting for Macavity to post an answer

Answer (score 5):

The general strategy is to show that, without loss of generality, the $a_i$'s must be of a specified form.  If not, we could replace the $a_i$ by another sequence with the same sum but equal or larger cyclic product of absolute differences.  All of our replacements below are of this type.  [We include a running example in brackets.]

Then it will be enough to maximize that product over all sequences of the specified form.

[Ex: .85, .98, .18, .34, .21, .74, .92, .20, .08]

**Wlog, the smallest $a_i$ is zero.**  If not, let $b=\min(a_i)$.  We can replace one minimal $a_i$ with $0$, and replace each of the other $a_i$ by $a_i+\frac{b}{n-1}$.

[Ex: .86, .99, .19, .35, .22, .75, .93, .21, .00]

**Wlog, any three consecutive $a_i$ include at least one zero.**  If not, suppose that the $a_i$ contain the subsequence $0,b,c,d,e$ with $b,c,d$ positive.  Let $m$ be the average of $b,c,d$.

- If $d>e$ and $d \ge m$, then we can replace $0,b,c,d$ by $0,b+c,0,d$.
- If $d>e$ and $d \le m$, then we can replace $0,b,c,d$ by $0,2m,0,m$.
- If $d<e$ and $d \ge c$, then we can replace $0,b,c,d$ by $0,b+c,0,d$.
- If $d<e$ and $d \le c$, then we can replace $0,b,c,d$ by
  $0,b+\frac{d}{2},c+\frac{d}{2},0$.

[Ex: .955, 1.085, .00, .35, .22, .75, .93, .21, .00]

[Ex: .955, 1.085, .00, .57, .00, .75, .21, .93, .00]

[Ex: .955, 1.085, .00, .57, .00, .96, .00, .93, .00]

Mathematica can verify quickly that these replacements increase the product:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := Abs[x (y - x) (z - y)]
positive[s_] := {0 < b, 0 < c, 0 < d, m == (b + c + d)/3, s}
Simplify[f[b, c, d] <= f[b + c, 0, d], Assumptions -> positive[d > m]]
Simplify[f[b, c, d] <= f[2 m, 0, m], Assumptions -> positive[d < m]]
Simplify[f[b, c, d] <= f[b + c, 0, d], Assumptions -> positive[d > c]]
Simplify[f[b, c, d] <= f[b + d/2, c + d/2, 0], Assumptions -> positive[d < c]]
```

(WolframAlpha provides the same verifications [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7BAbs%5Bb(c-b)(d-c)%5D%20%3E%20Abs%5B(b%2Bc)%5E2%20d%5D,%200%3Cb,%200%3Cc,%200%3Cd,%20d%3E(b%2Bc%2Bd)%2F3%7D), [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7BAbs%5Bb(c-b)(d-c)%5D%20%3E%20Abs%5B4(b%2Bc%2Bd)%5E3%2F27%5D,%200%3Cb,%200%3Cc,%200%3Cd,%20d%3C(b%2Bc%2Bd)%2F3%7D), [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7BAbs%5Bb(c-b)(d-c)%5D%20%3E%20Abs%5B(b%2Bc)%5E2%20d%5D,%200%3Cb,%200%3Cc,%200%3Cd,%20d%3Ec%7D) and [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7BAbs%5Bb(c-b)(d-c)%5D%20%3E%20Abs%5B(b%2Bd%2F2)(c-b)(c%2Bd%2F2)%5D,%200%3Cb,%200%3Cc,%200%3Cd,%20d%3Cc%7D), by saying "no solutions exist" to a search for counterexamples; this uses a modern variant of Tarski's algorithm for determining when polynomials have solutions in the reals.)

**Wlog, any three consecutive $a_i$ include at least one zero; also there is at most one triplet in $a_i$ with signs $0,+,+$.**  If not, and the triplets are not next to each other, we can replace the subsequence $0,a,b,\ldots,0,c,d,\ldots$ with its rearrangement $0,a,b,0,c,d,\ldots,\ldots$.  Then if we have the subsequence $0,b,c,0,d,e,0$, we can assume wlog that $b>c$ and $d>e$, and can replace the subsequence with $0,b,0,d,0,c+e,0$.

[Ex: .955, 1.085, .00, .57, .00, .96, .00, .93, .00]

**Wlog, any three consecutive $a_i$ include at least one zero; also, whenever zero is followed by a single positive number, it is always the same positive number.**  If not, we can replace $0,b,0,c,0$ by $0,(b+c)/2,0,(b+c)/2,0$, and similarly with means of longer sequences.

[Ex: .955, 1.085, .00, .82, .00, .82, .00, .82, .00]

**So wlog, the sequence is of the form $0,b,c,0,d,0,d,\ldots,0,d$ with $b>c$.**

[Ex: .00, 1.085, .955, .00, .82, .00, .82, .00, .82]

The sum condition gives $d=(n-2b-2c)/(n-3)$.  This gives the product
$$b(b-c)c\left(\frac{n-2b-2c}{n-3}\right)^{n-3}$$
and we can maximize this by maximizing
$$\ln(b)+\ln(b-c)+\ln(c)+(n-3)\ln(n-2b-2c).$$
Setting partial derivatives equal to $0$ gives
$$\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{b-c}+\frac{-2(n-3)}{n-2b-2c}=0$$
$$\frac{-1}{b-c}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{-2(n-3)}{n-2b-2c}=0$$
Solving with the constraint $b>c$, $n>0$, we get
$$b=\frac{3+\sqrt{3}}{4},\ c = \frac{3-\sqrt{3}}{4}$$
which leads to the maximal sequence
$$0, \frac{3+\sqrt{3}}{4},\frac{3-\sqrt{3}}{4},0,1,0,1,\ldots,0,1$$
and its cyclic product of absolute differences
$$\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{16}.$$

Comment: @MartinR, you can also verify this in WolframAlpha:  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7BAbs%5Bb(c-b)(d-c)%5D+%3E+Abs%5B(b%2Bc)%5E2+d%5D,+0%3Cb,+0%3Cc,+0%3Cd,+d%3E(b%2Bc%2Bd)%2F3%7D ; http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7BAbs%5Bb(c-b)(d-c)%5D+%3E+Abs%5B4(b%2Bc%2Bd)%5E3%2F27%5D,+0%3Cb,+0%3Cc,+0%3Cd,+d%3C(b%2Bc%2Bd)%2F3%7D ; http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7BAbs%5Bb(c-b)(d-c)%5D+%3E+Abs%5B(b%2Bc)%5E2+d%5D,+0%3Cb,+0%3Cc,+0%3Cd,+d%3Emin(b,c)%7D ; http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7BAbs%5Bb(c-b)(d-c)%5D+%3E+Abs%5B(b%2Bd%2F2)(c-b)(c%2Bd%2F2)%5D,+0%3Cb,+0%3Cc,+0%3Cd,+d%3Cmin(b,c)%7D

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proof for $n=3$, perhaps that helps someone to solve the
general problem.

> Let $a, b, c$ be non-negative real numbers with $a+b+c = \frac 32$.
>   Then
>   $$ f(a, b, c) =  \vert (a-b)(b-c)(c-a) \vert \le \frac{3 \sqrt 3}{16} \, .
> $$ 
>   Equality holds if and only if $(a, b, c)$ is a permutation of
>   $$
>  (0,  \frac{3-\sqrt 3}{4}, \frac{3+\sqrt 3}{4} ) \, .
> $$

*Proof:* Without loss of generality we can assume that $a \le b \le c$.
If $a > 0$ then we can replace $(a, b, c)$ with
$$
 (a', b', c') = (0, b + \frac\delta 2, c + \frac\delta 2)
$$
where $\delta = \frac 32 - b - c$. Then $a'+b'+c' = \frac 32$ and
$$
 f(a, b, c) = (b-a)(c-b)(c-a) < b'(c'-b')c' = f(a', b', c') \, .
$$

Therefore we can assume that $a=0$ and it remains to 
maximize $f(0, b, c)$
for $0 \le b \le c, b+c = \frac 32$. It is convenient to set
$$
   b = \frac 34 - x \, , \quad c = \frac 34 + x \, , \quad 0 \le x \le \frac 34 \, .
$$
Then
$$
 f(0, b, c) = b (c-b) c = 2 x \left( \frac {9}{16} - x^2 \right) =: \phi(x) \, .
$$ 
An elementary analysis shows that  $\phi$ has a unique maximum on $[0, \frac 34]$, it is attained at $x_0 = \frac{\sqrt 3}{4}$, and
$\phi(x_0) = \frac{3 \sqrt 3}{16}$. 
This concludes the proof.

---

*Remark:* For arbitrary odd $n \ge 3$ the upper bound
 $\frac{3 \sqrt 3}{16}$ is best possible. For $n=3$ that has been
demonstrated above. For odd $n \ge 5$ equality holds for
$$
 (a_1, \ldots, a_n) = (0,  \frac{3-\sqrt 3}{4}, \frac{3+\sqrt 3}{4}, 0, 1, \ldots, 0, 1) \, .
$$